# object properties of mongoose response are undefined

Tags: mongoose

i am trying to retrieve data from mongodb collection "Task" using mongoose and making some new updates on them but tried to read some properties but they are undefined but when log the object itself i found it contains the data

```
db.Task.find({}).then(function(tasks){
    tasks.forEach(function(task){
       console.log(task.userData);
       //{name: "tom" , phone: "00912440"}
       console.log(task.userData.phone)
       //undefined
    })
},function(error){
    //error handling
})
```

what is the reason for that ?!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you use some schema for this collection doesn't contain these properties, just add them and try again.